# Why would a software need my IP address in authentication token?

Tags: authentication

I was looking at the authentication token used in my network requests to a software that we use at work. I noticed that this is not a general JWT OAuth token but some XML based token. I guess, old way of doing things. I am particularly interested as to why do they need my IP address?

Is there a legitimate security reason to need it? My guess is to ensure that no other machine can reuse the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a legitimate security reason to need it? My guess is to ensure that no other machine can reuse the token.

That is a pretty good guess! Depending on how the software is implemented, it could be that the software is restricted to internal use (within the company) & there is **IP whitelisting** enabled at authentication level of the software.

Therefore, an intruder would need to have the token itself and **prior information** on having the IP address as part of the token as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem like many more opinions are going to come on this. Accepting this answer.